# how can i speed up http request using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, httprequest

im making a simple code sending http requests over and over again to get some response that can be changed all the time, and its a little bit slow, i've tried to speed it up by using asyncio but it didnt worked with me

```
import requests
r = requests.Session()
url = 'https://example.com'
headers = {'user-agent: example'}
def a():
    while True:
        post = r.get(url, headers=headers).text
        if post == 'something':
            print(5)
        elif post == 'something-else':
            quit()
a()
```

Comment: How slow is it? You didn't mention any timings. I wouldn't be surprised if the server is limiting you just because of how frequently you are making those calls. How often within the span of 1 second is that value you are checking going to change? The only other thing I would suggest is that you reuse `requests.session()` instead of creating a new one each time

Comment: like one request per second or 2 seconds, I tried to do your suggestion but nothing have changed.

Comment: Can you show the updated code with the changes I suggested? Edit your question and add the code beneath it

Comment: sorry about the late response, i edited it